# Sharing an in-memory SQLite database between several applications

Tags: c, sqlite

It's possible to create an in memory SQlite database:

```
rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

but if I've understood [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) correctly, this database is local to the app that created it.

I have a requirement for an in memory SQLite database which can be accessed by several apps. Other than creating the database on a ramdisk, is there any way of doing this?

This is for an embedded linux platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't share an in-memory database across processes – it's *really* not designed to do that because it lacks the right sort of integrity promises (but which does mean it's faster) – so either put the database on more permanent storage (such as the ramdisk) or put the DB in a single process (the “database manager”) and use some form of local communication strategy (unix-domain sockets, named pipes, etc.) to allow the other processes to ask the database manager to do a query for them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to create the db on a ramdisk/tmpfs, if you want it to be in memory and share it with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the database (and a cross-process lock) in the process with the necessary lifetime in shared memory. All you have to do then, is treat it as any other shared memory resource (remembering to lock/unlock when accessing it). Unfortunately, I think this might require some meddling with SQLITE source to use the memory you provide (shared) rather than allocate its own.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/shm.h.html